# Identifying and removing carpet adhesive

Tags: adhesive, removal, carpet, asphalt

I removed the carpet in one of my rooms. Underneath I found the following carpet adhesive:[image]

The removal of the carpet was very easy, it came off easily. The adhesive is still tacky so you stick to it as you walk.

Unfortunately, it is not water-soluble. It's also difficult to scrape off.
I've already tried putting dish soap and vinegar on it, which unfortunately didn't help much.

[image]

Does anyone know what type of glue this is?
What is the best way to remove it?

I've read that brown adhesive can be toxic.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? (How smooth do you need things?)

Comment: If your last line relates to asbestos, lab test is the only way to be sure, if the age and location of the structure or carpet imply that as a possibility. Generally, tedious mechanical scraping is required to remove old adhesive. It might dissolve with different solvent, but that will be a fire hazard and a hazard to breathe, (and increase your odds for contact poisoning from solvent or adhesive dissolved in it) and still might not come all the way clean.

Comment: Imagine you are planning on putting down new flooring.  If you mention the flooring type, then quite possible can just cover over the adhesive with under layment.

Comment: @crip659: Yes, I'm planning to put laminate flooring. But I would prefer to remove the adhesive, just to be sure, that there is nothing toxic left.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: The house is from 1976, but I'm not sure, when the carpet has been put. It didn't look too old actually.

Comment: All these little details you've added comments would be good to [edit] into your question. A lot of times, the _why_ is just as important in providing you a good answer as the what. Also, just because something's toxic (like, say, asbestos), doesn't mean that you _have_ to remove it. Covering asbestos without disturbing it is often considered the _best_ option.

Comment: Carpet is not a good sealer, but you have living with the carpet and adhesive and are stilling living.  Imagine if it is toxic, it would be more likely to affect you when removing it than covering it.  Lead paint is toxic also, but quite safe if left alone, sanding lead paint without protection is when it affects you.

Answer (score 1):

With consideration of all the comments and the extra information. Vacuum the floor well. Remove any *hard* objects larger than about the size of a grain of rice. Then put down the usual underlayment for laminate flooring of foam and plastic. Tape the seams. Lay the flooring and enjoy your room.

The glue has been there for decades covered by carpet, ( that doesn't seal anything.) and you haven't said you are terminally ill or have grown a horn.